# Trying to add opencv to a flutter plugin

Tags: android, opencv, flutter, plugins

Trying to add opencv to a flutter plugin. I have tried to follow example by Sawan Kumar Bundelkhandi. When I did an import module of OpenCV into the (java) project, it only shows me a name of :Java, not anything like openVClibrary4.0. Maybe that is my first problem.

Later, I cannot add the libs directory to the java project. I tried various right click, create Directory, but nothing seemd to be created. I did a copy in Windows explorer, and renamed it to jnilibs, but I cannot make the Android Studio project see that directory.

Any suggestions where I could look for more information?

Comment: More info: I have been following https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/a-guide-to-preparing-opencv-for-android-4e9532677809#69e6https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/a-guide-to-preparing-opencv-for-android-4e9532677809#69e6 by Ahmed Gad. This example is for a normal Android Studio java project, nit a flutter plugin. I think I was able to open openCV as a dependency because writing import org.opencv does show the openCV library entries.

Comment: ..I got a bit further. I used OpenCV3.3.1 rather than 4.0.1. I got a :A problem occurred evaluating project ':my_test_plugin'.
> Project with path ':openCVLibrary331' could not be found in project ':my_test_plugin'.   I will try again tomorrow, getting tired now

Comment: I feel your pain, I'm on that last "could not be found" step right now... only thing I notice is that Flutter build ignores plugin's gradle files where I declared opencv project's location. I have to find the build process behind Flutter build command...